# using activeuuid gem for existing database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to implement activeuuid gem to have UUIDs instead of default Rails ids. we can implement it for creating new migration as:

```
 class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students, :id => false do |t|
      t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And in model we include ActiveUUID::UUID as:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name
  include ActiveUUID::UUID
end
```

Now I already have a database so how can I implement the activeuuid gem to have UUIDs instead of default Rails ids for existing DB?
Need to make changes in all migrations or what?
Need help in this regard. thanks

Comment: Great question, I'm facing this same issue! Do you mind sharing what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 0):

The UUID is stored as a binary field w/ 16 positions as I found here: https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid/blob/master/lib/activeuuid/patches.rb#L62

It worked for me (existing table without records):

```
def change
  reversible do |dir|
    change_table :payments do |t|
      dir.up   { t.change :id, :binary, limit: 16, :primary_key => true }
      dir.down { t.change :id, :integer }
    end
  end
end
```

Don't forget to add those lines to your model as well:

```
include ActiveUUID::UUID
natural_key :at_least_one_field_here
```

More info in the github repo: https://github.com/jashmenn/activeuuid/